# Conditional expectation with brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-probability

I want to find $E[e^{σB_t}|∫_0^1B_s ds]$.
 I make the notation $∫_0^1B_s ds = z$, and I know that:
$E[B_t|Z]= 3t(1 - t/2)z $, $Var [B_t|Z] = t - 3t^2(1 - t/2)^2$ and $Var(∫_0^1B_s ds) = 1/3$.
The answer has to be an integral.

Comment: $B_t$ and the integral are jointly normal, so when you know the covariance you know everything.

Comment: So I find the covariance, and then the joint density function? Just a hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every centered normal $(X,Y)$ there exists $(a,b)$ such that $X=aY+bZ$ with $Z$ standard normal independent of $Y$. Thus, 
$$
E[\mathrm e^X\mid Y]=\mathrm e^{aY}E[\mathrm e^{bZ}]=\mathrm e^{aY+b^2/2}.
$$
To find $(a,b)$, note that $E(X^2)=a^2E(Y^2)+b^2$ and $E(XY)=aE(Y^2)$.

Applying this to $X=\sigma B_t$ and $Y=\int\limits_0^1B_s\mathrm ds$, one sees that $E(X^2)=\sigma^2t$, $E(Y^2)=\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\min(u,v)\mathrm du\mathrm dv=\frac13$, and, if $t\leqslant1$, $E(XY)=\sigma\int\limits_0^1\min(t,s)\mathrm ds=\sigma t(1-\frac12t)$.

To write the result as an integral (!), consider $Y_t=\int\limits_0^tB_s\mathrm ds$, then
$$
E[\mathrm e^{\sigma B_t}\mid Y]=1+a\mathrm e^{b^2/2}\int_0^t\mathrm e^{aY_s}B_s\mathrm ds.
$$

Comment: Can I write $E[X\mid Y] = a$, and $Var[X\mid Y] = b^2$, and then $E[\mathrm e^X\mid Y] = e^{YE[X\mid Y] + Var[X\mid Y]/2}$? Also I don't understand your integral and where does the 1 come from.

Comment: Note that $E[X\mid Y]=aY$, not $a$. // About the integral: try $t=0$.

Comment: Now I see. If Y is a known quantity, we don't need to integrate with respect to it.